# Why electrical appliances flicker and dims is it because of current drop, voltage drop or power drop?

Tags: current

In my house in India , suddenly one day night the lights flickered and turned dim I wonder is it because of current drop, voltage drop or power drop ?

Comment: It's because of all three at once. None of those can happen without the others, in a mostly-resistive load (such as lighting).

Comment: So, can we conclude it is due to insufficient power output from the source side i.e power plant

Comment: No. It can be because of some high winds causing some contacts to bounce somewhere on the power lines.

Comment: So what bouncing contacts in partial connection would lead to, drop of power or drop of voltage or drop of current?

Comment: Or perhaps your neighbor had an appliance that failed in such a way that it caused the power in your home to also be affected.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point about voltage, current, and power. They are strongly related, and in general they are all decreased or all increased.

Comment: Mr.B it is from the load side. Increased load draws more current. That causes a voltage drop. You see the effects of the voltage drop, because power usage is the result of voltage and current. When the voltage drops, the current drops also. So your power will be the square of the voltage.

Comment: There are lot of factors.  If you have a motor a long distance from panel, lights can dim as motor starts up.

Comment: So decreasing any one voltage or current or even power sometime causes the issue, so all these causes the lights to dim and it depends on the scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all ties together due to ohms law;

Most likely the AC voltage has dropped from let's say 230V to 200V for a brief period. This can be due to problems at the power plant or something drawing a large amount of current, causing the voltage to drop due to the resistive nature of wiring.

When the voltage in your home drops it will also make resistive appliances (like a light bulb) draw less current. E.g. a 60 watt light bulb which normally draws 3.8 amps will now draw 3.3 amps.

Less voltage and less current will equal in less electrical power being converted into light/heat; making the light dim/flicker.

Comment: So decreasing voltage will cause both current drop and power drop, now I understand It ,thanks everyone

Comment: Exactly! Please mark the question as answered :)